# Libvirt doesn’t recognize the network interfaces

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

so im using Virtual Machine Manager, and the sad part is that it doesn't list my interfaces.

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouFoP.png)
also if i run the iface command i get this :(

```
$ virsh iface-list
 Name   State   MAC Address  
-----------------------------
```

while if i run the command ifconfig i can see my eth0 interface just fine

i need to make it so the virtual machine manager detects my interfaces so i can create a bridge for my VMs instances :c

im using ubuntu 18.04 LTS with xfce4

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this part of the libvirt backend uses `netcf` which only can work with the pre `systemd-networkd` era of network configuration (read *not a new 18.04*).

Going forward Ubuntu switched to use udev backend instead (*>=Cosmic*).

You might be able to make Bionic work (unsupported) via:

```
apt install netcf libnetcf1 ifconfig
```

But that only works if you have an upgraded pre-`systemd-networkd` config. Therefore if you had upgraded from 16.04 with /etc/network/interfaces and this is still active then it will work. But if you have a new 18.04 install with systemd-networkd it won't be able to see those.

The problem here is the tradeoff between upgraders and new installs of 18.04 and potential regressions for one or the other group. See more details in bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1764314